# ggplot 2 cutting off end of x axis when legend is at the top

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to create a graph using ggplot, and have added in the `legend.position="top"` function into the theme section.

However this causes the end of my x-axis to be cut off (labels)

Just wondering if anyone knows if there is an easy fix for this?

Thanks

EDIT
Dataframe (I just used a set of 100 randomly generated numbers)

[image]

````
  geom_histogram(breaks=c(seq(0, 25, by=5)),col="white")+
  theme_light()+#removes background colour
  labs(x="Length in Cm", y="Frequency", )+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,25), breaks=c(seq(0, 25, by=5)), labels=c(seq(0,25, by=5)), expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,25), breaks = c(seq(0,25,by=5)))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#41ae76", "#006d2c"), name="")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),legend.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 16),legend.position = "top", axis.title = element_text(size = 20),legend.key=element_rect(fill="white"))```
````

Comment: Please include a working dataset with the script you have tried.

Comment: Your data should be in text format and not image

Comment: How do I paste it in text format? I have tried to do this before an had issues with the formatting

Comment: @timeywimey Please include sample data as code/text (delete the image); e.g. you can use `dput` on the `data.frame` and then copy&paste the output as text into the main post (not as a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest simplifying your plotting routine (there are quite a few redundant & unnecessary statements).

```r
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(Length, fill = Group)) +
    geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 25, by = 5), col = "white") +
    theme_light() +
    labs(x = "Length in Cm", y = "Frequency") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 25)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 25)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#41ae76", "#006d2c"), name = "") +
    theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.position = "top", 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.key=element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

This produces

[image]

Some selective & further comments:

1. Remove the `expand` arguments of `scale_*_continous`. They are likely to be responsible for cutting off text.
2. No need for duplicating `breaks` inside `geom_histogram` and `scale_x_continuous`.
3. The `breaks` argument to `scale_y_continous` is unnecessary.
4. There are lots of `theme` alterations to `theme_light()`. Perhaps better start with a more minimalistic `theme_minimal()` which will require less `theme` alterations.
5. I would strongly recommend using a consistent code indentation & formatting style to help with readability.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- structure(list(
    Length = c(19, 23, 19, 21, 21, 21, 2, 17, 1, 20, 
               14, 12, 5, 17, 13, 14, 14, 6, 18, 11, 8, 20, 2, 5, 17, 23, 8, 
               1, 11, 11, 15, 11, 7, 23, 21, 3, 11, 9, 6, 8, 5, 21, 10, 17, 
               24, 12, 11, 3, 16, 5, 10, 12, 12, 23, 19, 25, 17, 7, 10, 25, 
               5, 21, 12, 7, 10, 17, 1, 25, 11, 15, 25, 14, 13, 2, 1, 6, 1, 
               24, 13, 17, 7, 25, 19, 17, 2, 5, 5, 23, 3, 17, 21, 8, 2, 8, 13, 
               1, 4, 2, 20, 20), 
    Group = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", 
              "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
              "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", 
              "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
              "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", 
              "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
              "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", 
              "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
              "a", "b")), 
    row.names = c(NA, -100L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
              "data.frame"))
```